# Taking Limits in Inequality for Hausdorff Measure

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I'm trying to show that when $\mathcal{H}^a(K) > 0$ and $b < a$ then $\mathcal{H}^b(K) = \infty$. I did this by considering a cover $K \subset \{U_i\}$ of radius $\delta$. Then $$\sum|U_i|^a = \sum|U_i|^{a-b}|U_i|^b \leq \delta^{a-b}\sum|U_i|^b$$This implies $\left( \frac 1 \delta\right)^{a-b}\mathcal{H}_\delta^a \leq \mathcal{H}_\delta^b$. Taking $\delta \rightarrow 0$ gives the result.

I'm uncertain about my work because of the way $\delta$ is being used to take limits in the inequality.  Is this okay?

Comment: This also works: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448376/simple-questions-about-hausdorff-measure?rq=1

Comment: I don't see what the problem with limits is, this all seems fine...